# Dynamically Change Background Color

Tags: javascript, css

If I have an element and I'm listening for a click on the document (can be anywhere, this part doesn't matter), and with each click, I want the element to get darker in color, how can I logically or numerically change it?

This is what I tried:

```
    on('click', function() {

        var myElementBG = myElement.backgroundColor;

        myElement.style.backgroundColor = myElementBG - 101010;
    });
```

The problem here is that myElementBG returns "#707070", so trying to subtract 101010 from it yields NaN error since the '#' is part of the value.

Any ideas?

Comment: They 2 answers below make sense, but for the question's sake lets pretend I could NOT get the value in RGB or HSL, how would I remove the '#' to do a numerical operation on the hex value?(assuming that I never fall into a-f)

Comment: You can remove the # symbol with val = val.replace('#', '') but you'll get a string, so you can't do numerical operations on it. You'll have to parse it like that dec = parseInt(val, 16), do the numerical operations and then make it hex again with hex = dec.toString(16). BTW style.backgroundColor is returning rgb() in all browsers I have.

Comment: Thanks, that's perfect. Yeah, I'm working in some proprietary JS framework that returns in hex, the example above is just for reference.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

[JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/79Mzk/5/)

```
function subtractColorsHex(a, b) {
    a = a.replace('#', '');
    // We don't expect '#' symbol in b
    var decA = parseInt(a, 16);
    var decB = parseInt(b, 16);
    var resultDec = decA - decB;
    var resultHex = Math.abs(resultDec).toString(16);

    return "#" + "000000".substring(0, 6 - resultHex.length) + resultHex;
}
```

Usage:

```
subtractColorsHex('#070707', '101010');
```

Comment: Why is it chopping the first 0 off?

Comment: @RenaissanceProgrammer I think it's OK now.

Answer (score 1):

You can use hsl() values where the l portion stands for lightness where 0% is black and 100% is white.  There is good support for in all major browsers except IE 8 and below.

Comment: Thanks man, I'll try either the RGB method or the HSL method.

Answer (score 1):

I would save the value of the color (without the '#') in another place, for example as an attribute of the div. Then you can easily increment/decrement this value and set it as the actual background color.

I've made an example (I used jQuery to illustrate this but the idea is valid in pure javascript too).

**[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/_abl/nJn2s/)**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("div").attr("data-color", "F0F0F0");

    paintBackground();

    $(document).click(function(){
        makeDivDarker();
    });
});

function makeDivDarker(){
    $div = $("div");
    var currentColor = parseInt($div.attr("data-color"), 16);
    var newColor = currentColor - parseInt("101010", 16);
    $div.attr("data-color", newColor.toString(16));
    paintBackground();
}

function paintBackground(){
    var $div = $("div");
    $div.css("background-color", "#" + $div.attr("data-color"));
}
```

Comment: Thanks, this is helpful, but I won't always know the color beforehand so can't apply an attribute to scrub.

Answer (score 0):

Rather than go with HEX code, why not use RGB colors for the background, and then you can use Jquery to gradually reduce each value (RGB).

Comment: Thanks man, I'll try either the RGB method or the HSL method.